# Can I use visNetwork package to create a family tree? (like pedigree)

Tags: r, visnetwork

I want to create a family tree using visNetwork package.

I am trying to create a **family tree** using visNetwork package. I have tried using rpart object within visTree,but I do not know how to include data so that family tree appears. Is it possible to obtain family tree (such as pedigree) using **rpart and visTree**.

I have read about visTree from the following link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visNetwork/vignettes/Introduction-to-visNetwork.html

I would like my family tree to appear in such way (like the first plot that appears in the above link), but the above example shows how to create regression/classification tree.